# I can never add new user to access to my network Shared Folder (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing

Here at my place, there is a Windows 10 Home Edition PC act as the "server" in which this PC shares a folder in D:\ with a few other specific computers in the network. The shared folder is "Games"
Full path at "server" : **D:\Games**

To access to this network drive, other PCs that were previously configured can simply access by typing **"\office\Games"**

I have a new laptop and I want to access to "\office\Games" like other PC.
However, when I try to type the network address, i get the following error:
*"Windows cannot access \office\Games
You do not have permission to access \office\Games"*

I tried to disabled firewall in new PC, and allowed File sharing for private and public network in new PC.
I have also tried to add a new account in Windows Credential page.

Nothing works.

Bear in mind that there is no AD as everyone is using Windows 10 Home at non-commercial place.

I tried going to the "server" PC but I couldn't find a way to grant my laptop to the folder permission as it can't search for my PC name nor any other PC. I have since stuck for a week.

I am thinking the only step i missed out is the windows credential part pairing with folder permission but I have never found any guides online for Windows 10 Home without AD....all guides i found online are Windows 10 Business with AD so any PC can be found easily.

***Update : I read more guides on superuser. It seems that "server" and client PCs have to have the same exact credentials in Windows Credential Manager. Is this true?

I need help badly.